# installation 14.04 - Machine does not restart - stopping early crypto disks ok

Tags: system-installation, preinstallation

This is my first time to install Ubuntu version is 14.04 desktop.

After installation on a virtual machine (Hyper V), It says to restart. 
IT will stop at:

stopping early crypto disks      ok

Then it will stop here and it seems I have to shutdown the virtual machine to restart Ubuntu.

I am not sure if my installation is complete or not.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

See this answer:

[What is ubuntu 14.04 doing while showing "stopping early crypto disks"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501722/what-is-ubuntu-14-04-doing-while-showing-stopping-early-crypto-disks)

I killed the VM, went into (for that VM) Settings | System, and removed the Floppy (!) and CD/DVD from the boot order (leaving just Hard Disk). After that I haven't had this problem again.