# What is ubuntu 14.04 doing while showing "stopping early crypto disks"?

Tags: virtualbox, restart

I created a virtual machine to install ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox 4.2.12.*. I created virtual CD to install it with fixed-size virtual disk of 200GB. After successful installation, it restarted as usual. But after showing message of below, it hangs. Actually, I created virtual machines to install ubuntu at Virtual Box successfully several times. It's very easy. The installed ubuntu versions ranged from 9.10, 13.04 and even 14.04 before. I don't know why this time it hangs at restarting after successful installation. The only difference between this failure restart and previous successful ones is that the virtual disk is much larger, 200GB. It failed three times.

```
* Deactivating swap... [OK]
* Stopping remaining crypto disks... [OK]
* Stopping early drypto disks... [OK]
```

Comment: I figured it out. When I installed it, I set the first boot media as CD-ROM. After installation, I must change it to HardDisk.
The strange is that in previous cases, VirtualBox did it automatically. I used VirtualBox to install and use ubuntu several times successfully. I don't remember I changed boot priority by myself before. Anyway, it works now.

Answer (score 9):

The OP solved their problem and explained how in a comment:

> I figured it out. When I installed it, I set the first boot media as
>   CD-ROM. After installation, I must change it to HardDisk. The strange
>   is that in previous cases, VirtualBox did it automatically. I used
>   VirtualBox to install and use ubuntu several times successfully. I
>   don't remember I changed boot priority by myself before. Anyway, it
>   works now.

–  Stan Huang at Taiwan [Jun 27 at 7:38](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501722/what-is-ubuntu-14-04-doing-while-showing-stopping-early-crypto-disks#comment673743_501722)

Comment: This answer isn't correct. The hang is caused by a bug in installer shutdown process [(bug #966480 - The prompt asking for media removal is not shown at the end of the installation)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/966480). Doing a manual reboot (_Machine>Reset_) at this point will bypass the hang. It is not necessary to change the boot-media setting in VirtualBox - nothing has changed between VirtualBox versions in this regard.

Comment: The answer by @bain works :)